Does systemd always clone the parent process's mount namespace?
The description of the PrivateMounts setting of the systemd execution environment configuration documentation says

File system namespaces are set up individually for each process forked off by the service manager.

Does this happen always or only when PrivateMounts=true?

If you look through the rest of that documentation, you'll see there are other options whixh effectively enabled PrivateMounts even if you didn't set it.

Thanks for your comment. Are you implying that the specific behaviour described by my quote does indeed only happen when PrivateMounts=true explicitly or implicitly due to one of the options you're referring to?

Both of those cases.
